# Loading data from the datasets package in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using the following code in knitr

````
```{r,results='markup'}
library(datasets)
toothgrowth = data(ToothGrowth)
summary(toothgrowth)
toothgrowth
```
````

When I run the code directly in RStudio, the data is loaded just fine. But when I generate the HTML, the data set is just one element:

```
summary(toothgrowth)
Length     Class      Mode 
     1 character character
```

I'm new to R and this could be something silly, but I cannot figure out what's going on with knitr. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your use of `data()`. According to `?data`, the function will return "A character vector of all data sets specified, or information about all available data sets in an object of class..." rather than the dataset itself. Calling `summary()` directly on `ToothGrowth` will suffice.

Comment: Exactly. This answer has explained the problem well.